# How to configure 2 databases in the root-context.xml in spring mvc project? please provide me any suggessions

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, configuration, ibm-midrange

```
 <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:as400://**.*.**.*/" />
        <property name="username" value="******" />
        <property name="password" value="******" />      
    </bean>  
<bean id="homedao" class="com.bsdealer.daoImpl.DashboardImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

This is my current configuration and i need to add mysql configuration too, so i have added these line but getting some errors.

```
<bean id="dataSource2"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="username" value="****" />
        <property name="password" value="****" />      
    </bean> 


<bean id="testdao" class="com.bsdealer.daoImpl.testImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
    </bean>
```

**I have also added the error logs here:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource2' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
    ... 56 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this line of stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver]
```

it seems that you don't have MySQL JDBC driver jar on the classpath.

Comment: I have added driver class as well in configure build path